Cannot access data passed to shareable interface method in javacard
I new to javacard applet programming and trying to understand shareable interface to call a applets method in another applet. Below is my setup
sourceapplet.java is the applet where my shareable interface is implemented. And from targetapplet.java I am trying to call that interface.
sourceapplet.java

public void checkNumber(byte[] number) {
    short numberLength = (short)number.length;
    if (numberLength < 6) {
        ISOException.throwIt(ISO7816.SW_CONDITIONS_NOT_SATISFIED);
    }
    ISOException.throwIt(ISO7816.SW_WRONG_DATA);
  }

Configurations.java

public interface Configuration extends Shareable {
    public void checkNumber(byte[] number);
}

targetapplet.java

public final class TargetApplet extends Applet implements MultiSelectable {
    private static final byte INS_TEST_CHECK_NUMBER = (byte) 0x11;
    private AID checkNumberAppletAID;
    private TargetApplet() {
        // Initialize the AID of the checkNumberApplet
        byte[] aidBytes = {(byte) 0xB2, 0x86, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x01};
        checkNumberAppletAID = JCSystem.lookupAID(aidBytes, (short)0, (byte) aidBytes.length);
        
        if (checkNumberAppletAID == null) {
            ISOException.throwIt(ISO7816.SW_FILE_NOT_FOUND); // Applet not found
        }
    }

    public void process(APDU apdu) {
        final byte[] buffer = apdu.getBuffer();
        final byte ins = buffer[ISO7816.OFFSET_INS];
        switch (ins) {
        case INS_TEST_CHECK_NUMBER:
            processCheckNumber(apdu);
            break;
        default:
            ISOException.throwIt(ISO7816.SW_INS_NOT_SUPPORTED);
        }
    }

    private void processCheckNumber(APDU apdu) {
        Configuration config = (Configuration) JCSystem.getAppletShareableInterfaceObject(checkNumberAppletAID, (byte) 0x00);
        if (config == null) {
            ISOException.throwIt(ISO7816.SW_APPLET_SELECT_FAILED);
        }
        
        byte[] number = new byte[]{1,2,3,4};
        // byte[] number = new byte[] {(byte) '1', (byte) '2', (byte) '3', (byte) '4'};
        config.checkNumber(number);
    }
}

Now when I send apdu 00 11 00 00 I get 6F00 (SW_UNKNWON) response but I expect to get SW_CONDITIONS_NOT_SATISFIED response. However when I don't do any operation on the passed number array  in checkNumber method then I get SW_WRONG_DATA response as expected.
public void checkNumber(byte[] number) {
    /* short numberLength = (short)number.length;
    if (numberLength < 6) {
        ISOException.throwIt(ISO7816.SW_CONDITIONS_NOT_SATISFIED);
    } */
    ISOException.throwIt(ISO7816.SW_WRONG_DATA);
  }

can anyone please let me know what is the issue here and how to resolve it? is there any issue with number array that is passed in processCheckNumber in targetapplet.java?
Thanks in advance.
Update
Using transient memory in targetapplet.java
private byte[] number;
    private TargetApplet() {
        number = JCSystem.makeTransientByteArray((short) 4, JCSystem.CLEAR_ON_DESELECT); // Also tried with CLEAR_ON_RESET
        // Initialize the AID of the checkNumberApplet
        byte[] aidBytes = {(byte) 0xB2, 0x86, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x01};
        checkNumberAppletAID = JCSystem.lookupAID(aidBytes, (short)0, (byte) aidBytes.length);

        if (checkNumberAppletAID == null) {
            ISOException.throwIt(ISO7816.SW_FILE_NOT_FOUND); // Applet not found
        }
    }
    private void processCheckNumber(APDU apdu) {
        Configuration config = (Configuration) JCSystem.getAppletShareableInterfaceObject(checkNumberAppletAID, (byte) 0x00);
        if (config == null) {
            ISOException.throwIt(ISO7816.SW_APPLET_SELECT_FAILED);
        }

        number[0] = 1;
        number[1] = 2;
        number[2] = 3;
        number[3] = 4;
        config.checkNumber(number);
    }

Using persistent memory in targetapplet.java
private byte[] number;
    private TargetApplet() {
        number = new byte[4];
        // Initialize the AID of the checkNumberApplet
        byte[] aidBytes = {(byte) 0xB2, 0x86, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x01};
        checkNumberAppletAID = JCSystem.lookupAID(aidBytes, (short)0, (byte) aidBytes.length);

        if (checkNumberAppletAID == null) {
            ISOException.throwIt(ISO7816.SW_FILE_NOT_FOUND); // Applet not found
        }
    }
    private void processCheckNumber(APDU apdu) {
        Configuration config = (Configuration) JCSystem.getAppletShareableInterfaceObject(checkNumberAppletAID, (byte) 0x00);
        if (config == null) {
            ISOException.throwIt(ISO7816.SW_APPLET_SELECT_FAILED);
        }

        number[0] = 1;
        number[1] = 2;
        number[2] = 3;
        number[3] = 4;
        config.checkNumber(number);
    }

Update2
Added try-catch in sourceapplet.java
public void checkNumber(byte[] number) {
    try {           
        short numberLength = (short)number.length;
        if (numberLength < 6) {
            ISOException.throwIt(ISO7816.SW_CONDITIONS_NOT_SATISFIED);
        }
    } catch (ISOException e) {
        ISOException.throwIt(e.getReason());
    } catch (SecurityException e) {
        ISOException.throwIt(ISO7816.SW_SECURITY_STATUS_NOT_SATISFIED);
    }
  }

And now I get 6982 SW_SECURITY_STATUS_NOT_SATISFIED response
P.S: please let me know if any info is missing

Before answering as the question might not be what you think it is, is there a specific reason you need this to happen with 2 applets instead of just one and having all the code within the TargetApplet (you can still have more than 1 class in TargetApplet cap file if you want).

Yes, the sourceapplet has some other logic and functionality which should not be part of targetapplet. Only the shareable interface method should be accessible in targetapplet.

For sharing array data between applets you should use the APDU buffer that is excluded from access control checks.
Newer Java Card specifications introduced global arrays and Array Views (see  JCSystem.makeGlobalArray() and JCSystem.makeArrayView() if you have them available).
For details see the Java Card Runtime Specifications.

Would defining the array as a field maybe make a difference? Not sure if we could share byte arrays before, but locally defined arrays is not a good idea anyway. OTOH, a reference is a reference.

@vip, I used the JCSystem.makeGlobalArray() as JCSystem.makeGlobalArray(JCSystem.MEMORY_TYPE_PERSISTENT, length) where length is short length = apdu.setIncomingAndReceive();. Also tried with JCSystem.ARRAY_TYPE_BYTE option. But it all resulted in 6982 or 6F00 response...

@MaartenBodewes do you have any other alternatives rather than using locally defined arrays?

@Preeti Set the 1,2,3,4 bytes in the APDU buffer instead and pass APDU buffer to the checkNumber() method.

@vlp, I modified it to send byte[] buffer = apdu.getBuffer();      buffer[ISO7816.OFFSET_CDATA] = (byte) 1;         buffer[ISO7816.OFFSET_CDATA + 1] = (byte) 2;         buffer[ISO7816.OFFSET_CDATA + 2] = (byte) 3;         buffer[ISO7816.OFFSET_CDATA + 3] = (byte) 4; config.checkNumber(buffer); Is it what you meant? With this I get 9000 response. but since the length is less than 6 as checked in sourceapplet.java I expected to get SW_CONDITIONS_NOT_SATISFIED. Is there anything I need to modify in sourceapplet.java ?

The source applet gets the complete APDU buffer -- so the length corresponds to it's size (typically 250+ bytes). If you want to trace the length of exchanged data you must pass it along the data itself (as a new argument to the shared method /maybe together with an offset/).

Please also pay attention not to expose some sensitive data to the second applet in the APDU buffer. It might be a good idea to erase it completely before passing it to the shared method.

@vlp, maybe OwnerPIN is suitable for this task? https://docs.oracle.com/javacard/3.0.5/api/javacard/framework/OwnerPIN.html

If your task is to verify PIN then OwnerPIN (and maybe a global PIN, if your card supports it) is suitable. Read the documentation about sharing in the OwnerPIN javadoc. For the global PIN see the docs related to this snippet: CVM ret = GPSystem.getCVM(GPSystem.CVM_GLOBAL_PIN); (your card needs to support it and applet needs extra privileges to control it).

@vlp, I will have to perform other tasks including checking if pin is in ascending order or not in sourceapplet. but can I use OwnerPIN to pass pin data from targetapplet to sourceapplet? Do you have any examples for using OwnerPIN for such cases?

OwnerPIN is OwnerPIN. Take a look at its features and decide yourself according to your task. If sourceapplet needs to perform some extra logic before the PIN is verified than just perform this logic before actual verification. I am afraid that all these decisions are beyond the scope of this question.

@vlp thanks for the info. So to perform these logics before PIN verification using OwnerPIN in sourceapplet I need to get actual data array in sourceapplet that's passed to sio in targetapplet, right? But that seems not to work for me. Do you have suggestions for this?

Use the APDU buffer.

okay, so if I call checkNumber in targetapplet as config.checkNumber(apdu.getBuffer()); then this will also send the header data to sourceapplet right? So I need to include ISO7816.OFFSET_CDATA to specify where the data starts in the APDU buffer, correct? And use ISO7816.OFFSET_CDATA to retrieve data in sourceapplet... Please correct me if I am wrong here

You may change checkNumber(byte[] number) to checkNumber(byte[] number, short offset, byte length). In targetapplet copy the (1,2,3,4) to the APDU buffer at some offset (for example 0). And then call checkNumber(apduBuffer, 0, 4); in the Shareable interface. This way you should get the (1,2,3,4)  to the sourceapplet and process it there. Pay attention not to expose any other sensitive data (if present) via the APDU buffer.

@vlp earlier I used a number array to store the apdu buffer data like byte[] number = new byte[length]; and copied the buffer data to this and called checkNumber(number); so I think this stored the number array in transient array which cannot be passed to sio, right? Also is there any method to clean the sensitivie data before sharing it?

AFAIK new byte[length] allocates a new persistent memory based array (in contrast to JCSystem.makeTransientByteArray() that should be used to get a transient array). And yes, such arrays cannot be passed via sio. You can use Util.arrayFillNonAtomic to wipe array contents. Please do validate my thoughts with the respective JCRE specifications for your platform.

even I thought so, but passing such array doesn't work for me. instead I have to pass apdu.getBuffer() to sio...

sorry this is not related to OP, but can you please let me know how can I return the buffer from shareable interface to targetapplet? for example, if I create a buffer in targetapplet as final byte[] buffer = new byte[255]; and pass this buffer to sio, write some data into this buffer in sourceapplet and want to send back the updated buffer back to targetapplet ?

AFAIK, any changes made to the array (i.e. the APDU buffer) by the sourceapplet during SIO processing will be visible to the targetapplet when SIO call returns.

yes, that is correct. If I directly send apdu.getBuffer() to sio and write some data into this buffer in sourceapplet, this change is visible in targetapplet when sio call returns. however if I first create a buffer final byte[] buffer = new byte[255]; and use this buffer then the changes are not visible. Using a separate buffer is good as then I don't have to send original apdu buffer...

As far as I know you cannot send arbitrary byte arrays (persistent or transient) via the shareable interface and the only exception is to use the APDU buffer on most of the cards. Please do read the relevant specifications.

@vlp, hi, I have a small question: can we send boolean values to shareable interface object? or only byte, short and array (apdu buffer) allowed?

AFAIK it should be possible.

You are calling the shareable interface with a local stack referenced array.
    byte[] number = new byte[]{1,2,3,4};
    config.checkNumber(number);

As you then do operations on that object the system will cause exceptions.
Not everything can be shared across shareable interfaces, and there is a lot to consider when you do so. It is also in general less secure. Passing a short instead of an array would probably fix this. But there might be more things in regards to initialization of the applets as well.
There are multiple Stack Overflow questions on the same topic like
Shareable Interface in Javacard: use cases and implementation
JavaCard: How can an applet's instance call a method in another instance's context?
I would also be very careful with calling new inside methods like above. You want to finish your memory allocations during initialization as there is no real garbage collector available.

thanks for the info. I tried with both persistent memory and transient memory but still get 6F00 response. I have update the OP with code block

I also tried with initializing shareable interface object in the processCheckNumber instead of TargetApplet() constructor. But the result is same.

I modified my sourceapplet.java to add try-catch block and now I get 69 82 SW_SECURITY_STATUS_NOT_SATISFIED response. Added in Update2 section in OP.

when I send short instead of an array then it works fine. however I want to send array in the end like byte[] number = new byte[]{1,2,3,4}; or array will be extracted from apdu

Yeah, the array you are creating isn't globally shared and the OS is blocking you from accessing it. You can test this with the APDU buffer, it is globally shared.
Marteen Bodewes has an example of a shared array in the second question I linked.

thanks for the hint. I now modified targetappplet.java to retrieve number aray from apdu buffer like byte[] buffer = apdu.getBuffer();      short length = apdu.setIncomingAndReceive();      byte[] number = new byte[length];      Util.arrayCopy(buffer, ISO7816.OFFSET_CDATA, number, (short) 0, length);          config.checkNumber(number);
and sending apdu 00 11 00 00 04 01 02 03 04 but still I get SW_SECURITY_STATUS_NOT_SATISFIED response. Is there anything I am missing here?

I am out of ideas and tries. only passing short works now

I'll see if I can set up a debug environment to spot what might be wrong after the weekend potentially.

Thanks @Asthor, I am looking forward for your findings

maybe OwnerPIN is suitable for this task? https://docs.oracle.com/javacard/3.0.5/api/javacard/framework/OwnerPIN.html

Not sure I follow. You are trying to make a separate applet to hold a pin basically? Then using OwnerPin is probably better. Like I said, if you want to do a dual applet like this on your card, you need to have a very good reason and I would avoid it if I could.

the sourceapplet should contain all validation logic and this method will be called by multiple targetapplets. So I don't want to include these checking in the targetapplet.

What reason would you have to not include the validation logic in the same applet?
Doing what you suggest would transfer all data between applets on shared data objects and potentially if you don't clean them, also leak data you don't want to leak.

If I clean the data then is it possible to do this? Atleast I would like to test this. But right now I cannot get the data that I passed to sio in targetapplet. Is there any changes required in sourceapplet to receive the data array that is passed from targetapplet?
